# on loading html through javascript, textbox value doesn't consider space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Below given is a fraction of code, which loads a table row dynamically through html. The table row has a textbox, which gets its value from the variable 'currentValue'. But if the content of 'currentValue' has a space in between, only the first word is displayed. Nothing after space is displayed in the textbox(In below code, only 'hello' is displayed). Please suggest some solutions other than setting value through separate javascript query.

```
    currentValue = 'hello world';

    tr.append("<td><input id="+ textBoxId1 + " class='MyTextBox1' type='text' name='parameter_label' value="+ currentValue +" maxlength="+stringMaxLength+"></input></td>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about the HTML you're producing. Suppose `currentValue` has `"something here"`:

```
<td><input id=someid class='MyTextBox1' type='text' name='parameter_label' value=something here maxlength=40</input></td>
<!-- Notice ---------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    -->
```

Now it should be obvious what the problem is (and that there are two other problems): You don't have quotes around the `value` attribute's value. That's only valid when the value doesn't have spaces (or several other characters). [More in the specification.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0)

So we add them:

```
tr.append("<td><input id="+ textBoxId1 + " class='MyTextBox1' type='text' name='parameter_label' value='"+ currentValue +"' maxlength="+stringMaxLength+"</input></td>");
// Note -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^------------------^
```

That assumes that `currentValue` will never have `'` in it. If it might, you can use `"` instead:

```
tr.append("<td><input id="+ textBoxId1 + " class='MyTextBox1' type='text' name='parameter_label' value=\""+ currentValue +"\" maxlength="+stringMaxLength+"</input></td>");
// Note -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^------------------^^
```

*That* assumes `currentValue` will never have `"` in it, or that you've properly prepped `currentValue` (handling turning `<` and `&` into entities, as you must for all attributes, and also in this case turning `"` into `&quot;`).

The other two problems are:

1. You're missing the ending `>` on your `<input ...>` element.
2. Remove the `</input>`. `input` elements are *void elements*, they never have closing tags.

So:

```
tr.append("<td><input id="+ textBoxId1 + " class='MyTextBox1' type='text' name='parameter_label' value='"+ currentValue +"' maxlength="+stringMaxLength+"></td>");
```